# "too many braces around scalar initializer" error when using 2d array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am still learning C but when I try and use a 2d array I get the errors:

> ```
> /Users/harry/Dropbox/C/Practise/test_1/main.c:157:9: error: expected expression
> int[,] numberGrid = {  
>    ^   
> /Users/harry/Dropbox/C/Practise/test_1/main.c:158:9: warning: too many braces  
> around scalar initializer [-Wmany-braces-around-scalar-init]  
>     {1, 2, 3 },
> ```

My code is:

```
int main() {
    int[,] numberGrid = {
        {1, 2, 3 },
        {4, 5, 6 },
        {7, 8, 9 }
    };

    printf("%d\n", numberGrid[1, 1]);
}
```

Comment: The notation `int[,]` is not valid C.  You might mean `int numberGrid[3][3] = …`.

Comment: ... you can also _only_ omit the last dimension size in array initialization in C iirc

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When i change it to that i get a completely wrong the output is : -321090932

Comment: @HarryStanley  yeah, because as we've said, that's not the C syntax for declaring and accesing multi dims arrays. You need `numberGrid[1][1]`

Comment: Well, you must have modified the code so it compiles, so that is progress.  However, you should still be getting warnings from your compiler — you're using GCC (or possibly Clang), so you should be using `gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Werror …` for starters (for my own work, I add `-Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes` to those).  You seem to be influenced by a language other than C — such as Fortran, Pascal, Algol, Ada or ...  You can't usefully use commas in subscripts.  You need `printf("%d\n", gridNumber[1][1]);` to get `5` printed.  What you've got is the address of row 1 of the array.

Comment: Guessing C language syntax is not going to end well... try following a book or other reference that has examples of array usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the notation `int[,] numberGrid = { …` notation simply isn't C.

If you wrote either:

```
int numberGrid[3][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3 },
    {4, 5, 6 },
    {7, 8, 9 }
};
```

or:

```
int numberGrid[][3] = {
    {1, 2, 3 },
    {4, 5, 6 },
    {7, 8, 9 }
};
```

you would be able to get the array initializer to compile.

Then you need to fix the `printf()` to print an array element.  The comma is no use in subscripts in C (for most practical purposes, it 'never' appears in a subscript — you can invent exceptions if you try hard enough, but you shouldn't write such code normally).

You could write:

```
printf("%d\n", numberGrid[1][1]);
```

to print `5`.  As written (`printf("%d\n", numberGrid[1,1]);`), you are printing an address as a signed decimal integer, which is not guaranteed to work well (data truncation on a 64-bit machine, etc).

Comment: Thank you very much this helped alot tot understand where i went wrong.